# AES Decryption Issue - Returned Crypt from SagePay

Tags: c#, asp.net, encryption, aes, opayo

I am trying to decrypt a string sent back from SagePay Forms and am getting garbage back after the decryption.  I am unable to figure out why.  My decryption code is:

```
    public string AESdecrypt(string input)
    {
        return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(AESdecrypt(Convert.FromBase64String(input)));
    }

    public byte[] AESdecrypt(byte[] input)
    {

        //PasswordDeriveBytes pdb = new PasswordDeriveBytes("hjiweykaksd", new byte[] { 0x43, 0x87, 0x23, 0x72, 0x45, 0x56, 0x68, 0x14, 0x62, 0x84 });

        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
        Aes aes = new AesManaged();
        aes.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
        aes.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
        aes.KeySize = 128;
        aes.BlockSize = 128;
        aes.Key = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(conf["ENCRYPTPWD"]);
        aes.IV = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(conf["ENCRYPTPWD"]);

        CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(ms, aes.CreateDecryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write);
        cs.Write(input, 0, input.Length);
        return ms.ToArray();
    }
```

And the call to the encryption is:

```
uncrypt = _sagePay.AESdecrypt(Request.QueryString["crypt"].Replace("@"," "));
```

After the decryption I basically get gabbage

```
��z%3A %25�H��%0E�nS�%0A�M%01��)f%1F%13��D\����3l�%7F����2���%1F�%07gR�%0BoJ%05���c� %25Fm�hL��ݕz|�e�q���%3F���%24m�w%10�l*I����P%03%1F>�>`�ڸQ�%00I�����%0D�{%0D%0C�|%0D�p����)�9�%23�W4���wQo%3A�����.�V1�%0Dc��%3B%1F%15�M�a`o�B%0F%06�S�7H�%0D%15�H�A P)%26�ߵ4%17���C�}�g�7X��W\%11�H�Y�%2C��%08�xV%7FJ"��*%0A(2ޓ�%01%2F0��\�xcy��c�<�"%24%0AaX6���Y�%2Ci��O؇���UF%3F%14i��%3D'z%3B��{R<h8%1B%3A}��y�t5���Z�r�%00%07Z%3A�8�Ch�T��%11U�������Lv�]1j�E�ҳҖ{ �cq��4��%09T��as%1CO���B�M%3D�e�0%19|�%0C�.õ%0B�U�%14X��y���h%23%05!k�*����k%03��%10�C%1A�Z%25 %18%0Ci�%3F%0F�%12��l�̓�%2F��%0E%05�%02�Pc%02-����tAa%1C*%03�X>W�%3D%1C�%3Blg���8�1z�E�%2F�|�%17%06�%19N��aO%3F%12c�A�%40�%3Bt�%00�uɈ�2�%1F
```

I presume either I am encoding/decoding wrong or I am missing something during the decryption.

Comment: Are you sure that the AES key and IV are both the same string (the password)?

Comment: Good question. That's the way it's set up on encryption for the third party and that part works fine.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the required components to solve this mystery are missing from the question, e.g. a demo key, input, output and the encryption operation.

Comment: I think the specs may be at http://www.sagepay.co.uk/file/25041/download-document/FORM_Integration_and_Protocol_Guidelines_270815.pdf?token=JCKkSwlIntQop-nJHiGLxQpWXB2gLpwEYHtc7dZ7MNY

Comment: I've looked through the specs and they're too high level for the detail.

Comment: Well, at least from what I can tell from them, you are correctly configuring the crypto. You should call FlushFinalBlock on the Cryptostream before your `ms.ToArray()`, but that won't change the result in this case. My guess is that the password is incorrect.

Comment: The example in that spec document is *not* base64 encoded, its hex encoded. Maybe that's your issue?

Comment: Ah. Didn't notice that. I'll take another look. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is some c# code that decrypts the example given in section A1.2 of the [SagePay spec document](http://www.sagepay.co.uk/file/25041/download-document/FORM_Integration_and_Protocol_Guidelines_270815.pdf?token=JCKkSwlIntQop-nJHiGLxQpWXB2gLpwEYHtc7dZ7MNY). Most of this code is your code.

```cs
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Text;
using System.Runtime.Remoting.Metadata.W3cXsd2001;

namespace SagePayExample
{
    class SagePayExample
    {
        static String CipherHex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

        static String ENCRYPTPWD = "55a51621a6648525";

        public byte [] HexDecode(String HexString) {
            HexString = HexString.Replace ("@", "");
            SoapHexBinary converter = SoapHexBinary.Parse (HexString);
            return converter.Value;
        }
        public string AESdecrypt(string input)
        {
            return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(AESdecrypt(HexDecode (input)));
        }

        public byte[] AESdecrypt(byte[] input)
        {
            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
            Aes aes = new AesManaged();
            aes.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
            aes.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
            aes.KeySize = 128;
            aes.BlockSize = 128;
            aes.Key = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(ENCRYPTPWD);
            aes.IV = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(ENCRYPTPWD);

            CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(ms, aes.CreateDecryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write);
            cs.Write(input, 0, input.Length);
            cs.FlushFinalBlock ();
            return ms.ToArray();
        }

        public static void Main (string[] args)
        {
            var example = new SagePayExample ();
            var Decrypted = example.AESdecrypt (CipherHex);
            Console.WriteLine (Decrypted);
        }
    }
}
```